# Why left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable property or indexer?

Tags: c#, .net

```
private ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();

private ArrayList Test()
{
    return arr;
}
private void WhyMustVariable()
{
    Test() = new ArrayList();   // error: left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable property or indexer
}
```

Why cannot i do this Test() = ...;
Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean how can you *pass a variable to a method*? What would you expect your attempt to do?

Comment: Test() is a method, you can only assign values to properties and fields; arr = new ArrayList(), or arr = GetData().

Comment: Because what you're trying to do makes no sense.  You can assign a value to a *variable*, but you can't assign a value to a *method*.  What do you *expect* that code to do?

Comment: How do you think you'd access that new `ArrayList` afterwards? By the time that `Test()` returns, it's return value and the `arr` field have *no* relationship, despite the fact that one took a copy of the other.

Comment: what confused me is: now that  test().xyz = xxx is allowed, why test() = xxx is not.

Comment: So the left "Test()" is not a variable ? What is it.

Comment: @TangWentian: It's a call to a method.  I can't really imagine why you'd *think* it's a variable.  If that line of code *did* compile, what exactly would you expect it to do?  You can interact with the result of a method, you can assign the result of a method (or any other value) to a variable, but you can't *assign* to something that *isn't* a variable.

Comment: `private ref ArrayList Test() => ref arr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing `test().xyz = xxx` you first execute `test` which onbiously returns some instance of `ArrayList` (btw. you should consider to use `List<T>` instead nowadays, which is strongly typed and thus safes you from casting every element in your list to its actual type). Now You can of course do what you want with that instance, e.g. call another method or set any of its properties. This would be equivalent to doing this:

```
var val = test();
val.MyMember = 3;
```

However when using `test() = ...` you´re assigning a new value to the return-value of the method, which clearly makes no sense.

I suppose what you want instead is *provide* some parameter to your method. To do so your method also should *expect* one:

```
ArrayList test(int myInt)
{
    // do something with myInt
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var list = test(3);
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer.  As the error tell me, the left "Test()" is NOT a variable. But, in my opinion, Test() return arr, why Test() is not a variable..

Comment: @TangWentian No, it´s an expression who´s *result* can be *stored into* a variable.

Comment: @TangWentian - `Test()` *doesn't* return `arr`. It returns a reference to the same object that `arr` is currently referencing. As I indicated in the comments, by the time that it's become the return value from `Test()`, that return value and the `arr` field have *no* relationship.

Answer (score 1):

An assignment must have a place to store the value assigned, and this has to be a variable or a property (indexer is a special kind of property).

A property assignment is silently converted into a method call.

```
Test() = ...
```

where `Test()` returns something cannot be used as the target of an assignment because what is returned is a value, not a variable (nor a property).

Comment: I remember "property is a special method". (not sure, whether right or not).  property can be assigned, why method cannot.